# No me muestra el valor de suma

Tags: vue.js

no me muestra el valor de suma en el H3, solo me devuelve un NaN. Uso el framwork VUE Y compositionApi. Les agradezco por su ayuda...

```
<template> 
    <label>Ingrese numero 1</label>
    <input type="number" value="numero_1" >
    <label>Ingrese numero 2</label>
    <input type="number" value="numero_2">
    <h3>{{ suma }}</h3>
    <button @click="SumaNumeros">Sumar</button>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent,ref } from 'vue';
    export default defineComponent({
        name: "SumaComposition",
        setup(){
            let numero1=parseInt(('input[value="numero_1"]')); 
            let numero2=parseInt(('input[value="numero_2"]'));
            let suma = ref(0);
            const SumaNumeros=()=>{
               suma.value = numero1+numero2;
            }         
            return{suma,SumaNumeros} }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No conozco VUE pero me imagino que el fallo es que llamas a los input por su value, en lugar de eso, define name y llámalos por name, luego obtén value para los cálculos.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En VueJs se utilizan los atributos `v-model` para recoger el valor de los input.

Un ejemplo sería hacer lo siguiente:

En el template del componente reemplazarias `value` por `v-model` de los input:

```
<template> 
    <label>Ingrese numero 1</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="numero1" >
    <label>Ingrese numero 2</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="numero2">
    <h3>{{ suma }}</h3>
    <button @click="SumaNumeros">Sumar</button>
</template>
```

Y dentro del script setup lo controlarias del siguiente modo:

```
   setup(){
      let numero1 = ref(0);
      let numero2 = ref(0);
      let suma = ref(0);

      const SumaNumeros = () => {
        suma.value = numero1.value + numero2.value;
      } 
        
      return {
       suma,
       SumaNumeros
      } 
   }
```

Puedes aprender más sobre el atributo v-model aqui: [Documentación oficial](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html)

Comment: muchas gracias!!